# Hosting blogs in tumblr and redirecting custom page

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, tumblr

I've a blog hosted at tumblr (own domain).

Before that, I was hosting my blog using wordpress. When I was using wordpress, my permalink is like `<domain>/<year>/<month>/<date>/<article name>`, but after shifting to tumblr, the permalinks are now different.

So when people visit the old link, I want to make a 301 redirect; or at least prepare a custom page to inform them that the site has been changed.

How do I do that??

Comment: Was your wordpress blog on your own domain too? Did the pages have some sort of common URL like example.com/blog/domain etc. or was it example.com/domain etc.?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the same domain I was using for wordpress. No common URLs. Some of the posts are important so I want to manually redirect users who're visiting the old URL to the new URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create 301 redirects in tumblr using the 'Redirect' page type:

1. Click the settings cog in your tumblr Dashboard.
2. Click the 'Customize your blog' button.
3. Click the 'Pages' header.
4. Choose the 'Add a page' link.
5. Choose 'Redirect' from the 'Page Type' drop down.
6. Put your old WordPress URL in the "Page URL" field.
7. Put the new tumblr URL in the "Redirect to" field.
8. Click the "Create page" button.

[image: Redirecting a page in tumblr with a 301 header]

Requests for the old WordPress page will now result in a 301 (moved permanently) redirect to the new tumblr page. Note that every page has to be redirected manually. There's no wildcard system to create rules to handle mass forwarding, unfortunately.

There's also no dependable way to style 404 (not found) pages with tumblr's existing template code, so any pages you *don't* redirect will lead users to a dead end devoid of helpful suggestions or search boxes, like this one:

[image: Tumblr's 404 page isn't very helpful]

A possible workaround to improve usability and reduce bounce rate might be to edit your theme's template code and use jQuery to detect the title "Not found", and inject a more helpful error message into the post body below. How you do this depends on the theme in question, but it might look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-post">
    <h2>Not Found</h2>
    <p>The URL you requested could not be found.</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var pageTitle = $('div.text-post h2').text();
if (pageTitle == "Not Found"){
    $('div.text-post p').html('Your new helpful message goes here.')
}
```

[LIVE DEMO HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/kRUxK/)

Comment: You're welcome! I've added some jQuery sample code showing how you could improve tumblr's 404 page with JavaScript if you wanted to.